# Restful MVC Web Api Inheritance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Im building myself an asp.net mvc 4 web api

I've been through the [Microsoft videos](http://www.asp.net/web-api/videos/getting-started/your-first-web-api) and I think they are good. Http Verbs are used. Resources are nouns, it's dandy with repositories, etc.

**But one thing really bugs me**

I'm under the impression that this `GET http://www.myurl.com/api/sellers/{id}/products` is restful and `GET http://www.myurl.com/api/products?$filter = sellerID eq {id}` is not.

All I see in what I've read about the new web api is the <strike>former</strike> latter.

Is there native support for the <strike>latter</strike> former? If not, is there a way to do it **without routing everything**?

---

**Edit-**
Im looking for something that will allow `GET http://www.myurl.com/api/sellers/{id}/products` and `GET http://www.myurl.com/api/products` etc

---

**Update:**
This question didn't make sense for a while, I've fixed that, but that's why the first answer isn't marked as correct.

---

**Update:**
After chatting with MilkyWayJoe we talked about converting `/Seller/2/Products` to `/Products?$filter = sellerID eq 2`. Has anybody got any idea on how one can go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

The url `http://www.myurl.com/api/products?$filter= sellerID eq {id}` is using [OData](http://www.odata.org/) filters, which in the Web API is consumed out of the box when your controller is returning the collection as `IQuerable`. The default in VS 2012 is currently set to `IEnumerable`, which does not support OData.

You can find more about this [here](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/03/odata-service-with-asp-net-web-api.html) and [here](http://dotnet.learningtree.com/2012/04/03/exposing-iqueryableodata-endpoints-with-web-api/).

Comment: I'm sorry, I accidentally said the latter when I meant the former. I've edited and fixed the question.

Comment: @MrJD Look at Programming Hero's response. It's basically a different routing pattern which resembles rails' routes. Check [this](http://microformats.org/wiki/rest/urls) as well, you'll see there are other similar routes, e.g. `GET /people/1/edit` which is essentially a GET

Comment: I'm only prepending get to explicitly define a verb. Its not necessarily related to the question. That method would require me to route each nested situation for each endpoint. I want a way to abstract away from that.

Comment: I don't know how else you'd register routes to query based on FK (probably because of my lack of experience with url routing). I usually register routes for these scenarios similarly to that, and again, this is a convention that's pretty similar to rails and/or sinatra routes (if not exactly the same), so IMHO you'd have to register these other routes.

Comment: Would it be possible to register a "nesting" area, such as `{nestedArea}/products' and then somehow turn it into OData? Or somehow use the iQuerable result?

Comment: Not sure what exactly would be a nesting area in this case

Comment: Um, multiple parents. For example sellers to products. Or suppliers to sellers. /sellers/2/products

Comment: But that's exactly what that route is. The route definition @ProgrammingHero has shown will query products (in the sellers controller) based on the seller's id. You can change the return type to `IQuerable<Product>` and return the results like `return results.AsQuerable;` so you can use OData with it

Comment: Yes, but I would prefer to not have to specify every route. So I would want something like {parents}/products to pick up /sellers/2/products and turn it into /products?$filter = sellerID eq 2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13470/discussion-between-mrjd-and-milkywayjoe)

Comment: I can't tell you for sure as I cannot try it out right now, but it should probably work, and yeah, if it does you wouldn't need to define extra routes. Try it out and let us know.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to have nested resources (at least in URL construction), but there's not a great deal of support for in MVC; you'll have to do most of the work yourself.

Firstly, you'll need to create a route to deal with your structure:

```
url: "sellers/{sellerId}/products",
defaults: new { controller = "sellers", action = "GetProducts" }
```

Then, you'll want to create the `GetProducts` action on your "Sellers" controller, which this route should direct callers to:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(int sellerId)
{
    //TODO: Add query to return results.
}
```

The `sellerId` parameter will be passed in through the route and should be used to drive your query.

The major drawback to this approach is that the custom route makes it harder to generate URLs for links between resources, and when they get more complicated they can start matching URLs you didn't expect them to.

Comment: My question specified 'without routing everything'. This does work, however i don't want to have to create 4 routes for deep nesting for a single endpoint. Its just not efficient.

Comment: Alas, as I said, MVC4 does not naturally support what you're trying to do. You can make your routes re-usable by defining more parameters in them, but ultimately if you want to have a particular URL resolve to a particular action and controller, **the routing system was designed to solve this problem.**

Comment: I'm just looking for variable routing. Read the very end of the comments on MilkyWayJoe's answer. I mention converting routing parameters to an OData structure

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking for a solution to your same problem. I'm currently testing this solution.

First of all, change the Route:

```
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}/{id2}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Index", id2 = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Then, if you want a `SellersController`, write it as normal, but name all the action `Index' and use notations to route the http verb correctly. For example:

```
     [HttpGet]
     public List<Seller> Index()
     {}
```

Then, in `SellersController`, create actions naming them as your "internal" object (`Products`).

```
     [HttpGet]
     public List<Product> Products(int id)
     {}

     [HttpGet]
     public Product Products(int id, int id2)
     {}
```

In this way you can call

```
     GET /api/sellers
     or GET /api/sellers/99/products
     or GET /api/sellers/99/products/2
```

I'm actually testing this approach, so any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: That's clever. However it doesn't scale like I want. For instance. Let's say products can have reviews, and you want to request all reviews for seller 142. The request would look like: /sellers/142/products/reviews. That's a 3 level request. Sadly it seems your example can handle up to two