# MVC custom routing function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

This is a more specific version of another of my questions: [Restful MVC Web Api Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338232/restful-mvc-web-api), I hope an answer to this will help me answer that.

Im using ASP.NET web api,
I want to be able to route something like this: `[{object}/{id}]/{controller}/{id}`.
so i want an array of objects with optional `/{id}` ending with the 'api endpoint'.

I want to be able to route these:
`/houses`
`/houses/3`
`suburbs/3/houses`
`council/5/suburbs/houses`
`city/8/council/suburbs/houses`
ETC

**TO**

```
get(List<restRoute>parents, int id){
    ...
}
```

restRoute would be an object with a string for the object and an optional int (or guid etc) for the id

Does anyone know where i can start?
**I don't want to route every single one individually.**

Comment: I don't see how the 2 last urls you have shown correspond to the route. According to your route definition after the controller name you could only have an id. Also it's not clear why are you using `List<object>` as your action parameter. How do you expect the model binder to know what to do with this object?

Comment: Maybe you could generate the routes dynamically in `RegisterRoutes` in `global.asax`? Otherwise, I have no idea...

Comment: @DarinDimitrov i said the `/{id}` is optional. And i addressed the list object by editing the question slightly.

Comment: @TheJonasPersson How would you do that?

Comment: Which `id` is optional? Only the **last** token of a route can be optional.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I want all the end id's in the array to be optional. It doesn't make any sense to have them required

Comment: What's `{object}` in your route template? What defines the controller and action name from your route? For example you've put `{controller}` after the first `{id}` but with your first 2 urls, there's no controller defined. So how to map between those urls and the corresponding controller and action? Is it always the same controller? Another remark: in your route the id is optional. But in your action the id parameter is of type non-nullable integer which is impossible.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I just wrote object because I'm unsure what to call it. Its essentially a parent of the final object in the url (or endpoint). I want the controller to be decided by the endpoint. The action is GET POST PUT or DELETE as defined by MVC4 web api controller.

Comment: I am still unclear. I thought you want everything following the first `{id}` to be variable and be bound to a list. But now you confused me even more. Sorry I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. You are constantly modifying your question as well. Maybe that's what confuses me. And if the controller has to be part of the url why in your first 2 examples there's no controller specified? It is possible to have variable part of a route, but this should be the end, not the beginning: `{controller}/{id}/{*list}`. And then write a custom route to parse the `{*list}` token into an array.

Comment: Okay ill try be more specific. The part outside of the square brackets is required, inside is optional. square brackets represent an array, The array contains parents of the end of the url.

Comment: Alright, that's impossible. As I already said: optional parts goes at the **end** of a route definition. Not in the beginning. You might be able to achieve that by writing a custom route though.

Comment: Thats what i want to do. How do I do it?

Comment: By writing a custom route and using a catch-all definition. It's up to you to do the splitting and parsing in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `{*anything}` [Variable Segmented URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#handling_a_variable_number_of_segments_in_a_url_pattern) pattern in your route and handle the splitting up and figuring out of what part of the url corresponds to what bit of data in your method:

`Global.asax:`

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Special", // name
            "{*allthethings}", // parameters
            new { controller = "Special", action = "Sauce" } // defaults
        );
```

`SpecialController:`

```
public ActionResult Sauce()
{
    string data = RouteData.Values["allthethings"].ToString();
    string[] items = data.Split('/');
    foreach (string item in items)
    {
        // do whatever you need to figure out which is what!
    }

    return View();
}
```

If you wanted to be a bit cleverer about it you could create your own custom RouteHandler to do the splitting. Something like [David Ebb's PK routehandler](https://forums.asp.net/p/1281523/2457282.aspx#2457282) would probably do the trick, with some customisation to fit your requirements in the processing of the route. You could use this to split up the "allthethings" parameter and turn it into your `List<RestRoute>` format before passing the request on to the Controller

Comment: I ended up using this approach, it worked just fine as it allowed me to use a factory architecture with a single controller.

Answer (score 2):

I had also such problems with routing from the box in ASP.NET MVC. Its good way to be used as common routing, but is not so flexible for custom routs.

In WCF Web Api (ASP.NET web api in CTP version) was used attribute based routing.

I think its more flexible, but as negative point -  each method should have routing attribute.

Take a look at this blog post:

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/attribute-based-routing-in-asp-net-web-api/

It describes how to implement attribute based routing using ASP.NET Web Api. Because such approach is more flexible for routes you can map to methods, it can be helpful for you.

Comment: I've re-read that article a few times now. It makes what I want to do easier, but it isn't perfect since I'll have to manually add each possible attribute to each method. Having said that this is a good answer, so +1.

Comment: This attribute based routing library is open source with MIT license. As positive, you can look at this implementation as example and then implement your similar generic routing for your solution. Source code is hosted on Git https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting